# How Edit record using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I am trying to edit my db record using codeigniter but I can't do it and what's the problem I didn't understand. Please help.

Here is my **controller** code :

```
    public function edit()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','E-mail','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','Phone','trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            echo "error";
        }
        else{
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $this->crud_mdl->editCrud($id);
            echo "success";
        }
    }
```

Here is my **model** code :

```
    public function editCrud($id)
    {
        $update = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'phone' => $this->input->post('phone')
            );
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        return $this->db->update('test', $update);
    }
```

Here is my **view** :

```
    <div>
    <?php echo form_open('crud/edit');?>
    <?php foreach ($records as $record) {?>
    <label> ID </label>
    <input type="text" name="id" id="id" disabled="disable" value = "<?php echo $record->id ;?>" /><br/>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id ="name" value = "<?php echo $record->name ;?>" /><br/>
    <label>E-Mail</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id ="email" value="<?php echo $record->email ;?>" /><br/>
    <label>Phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id ="phone" value = "<?php echo $record->phone ;?>" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />
    <?php }?>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
```

Comment: did u checked whether u r getting value for array $update in model??

Comment: yes i checked iam getting updated value from array $update. but updated record is not saved into database.

Comment: If you r getting the values in model, then it should get updated as there is no any error in it as I can see.

Comment: make sure that you have loaded the model by $this->load->model('test'); and the keys of array $update have the name same as field name.

Comment: Better way to check for error in query is to echo it in model as, return $this->db->last_query();

Comment: if there is no any error why i can't update my record? could you plz check again that i have done everything perfectly.

Comment: Hey, SamV ID actually in POST from a disabled input field, look into my view code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `disabled="disable"` in your `input` for `id`. This means it won't be included in the form `POST`. You need to remove `disabled="disable"`.

Try that:

```
<label> ID </label>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $record->id ;?>" />
```

For proper practices you should set the input type to `hidden` instead or put the ID in the url (depends on your application).

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $record->id ;?>" />
```

Comment: Why would you want ID to be changed by the user ? Put it in type="hidden" ! And display it in a span or nothing.

Comment: I dont want it to be changed, i was just to pointing out that if there is a disabled attribute then it wont send. The ID should be in the URL ideally.

Comment: Although the accepted answer works, I think that BabyAzerty's answer is more appropriate as you don't want to have a form where you allow the id to be changed before it's posted.